# Read Flash ROM via Super I/O (Winbond W83627DHG)

Tags: c, linux, x86, spi, bios

I have an Intel DG41WV motherboard equipped with a [Winbond W83627DHG](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/206193/WINBOND/W83627DHG.html) Super-I/O and I'm trying to read the contents of the flash memory (Winbond W25Q80) via SPI through LPC.

The datasheet isn't exactly very descriptive of what to do, but it does say:

> **Reading Data From SPI Devices**
>
> First, write the “Read” instruction to Base+0. Then write the addresses to Base+2 ~
> Base+3. Last, write 8X to Base+1.

Fortunately, there is an additional document called "[W83627DHG
Programming Guide](http://www.bukowc.com/Galerija/Avtomobilizem/Stilo/CARPC3/Commell%20LS-373/W83627DHG%20Programming%20Guide%20V1_1.pdf)" and in it there is, in fact, a C code illustrating how to use this SPI interface.

The following code is a slightly modified version of the code provided in the aforementioned document and represents my attempt so far:

```c
#include <err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/io.h>

#define SIO_SPI_IOBASE 0x2E8

#define SIO_PORT       0x2E
#define SIO_REG_GLBOPT 0x24 /* Global Option. */
#define SIO_REG_LDSEL  0x07 /* Logical device select */
#define SIO_REG_ENABLE 0x30 /* Logical device enable */
#define SIO_REG_LD_SPI 0x06 /* SPI Logical Device. */
#define SIO_REG_IO_SPI 0x62 /* SPI I/O base address. */


/* Winbond W25Q80 commands. */
#define READ_CMD  0x03 /* Read data. */


static inline void sio_pnp_enter(void) {
    outb(0x87, SIO_PORT);
    outb(0x87, SIO_PORT);
}
static inline void sio_pnp_exit(void) {
    outb(0xaa, SIO_PORT);
}
static inline void sio_write_config(uint8_t reg, uint8_t value) {
    outb(reg,   SIO_PORT);
    outb(value, SIO_PORT + 1);
}
static inline void sio_select(int ld) {
    outb(SIO_REG_LDSEL, SIO_PORT);
    outb(ld, SIO_PORT + 1);
}
static inline void sio_set_enable(uint8_t enable) {
    sio_write_config(SIO_REG_ENABLE, enable);
}
static inline void sio_set_iobase(uint8_t index, uint16_t iobase) {
    sio_write_config(index + 0, (iobase >> 8) & 0xFF);
    sio_write_config(index + 1, iobase & 0xFF);
}


static void configure_spi(void)
{
    sio_pnp_enter();
        sio_write_config(SIO_REG_GLBOPT, 0x46);
        sio_select(SIO_REG_LD_SPI);
        sio_set_enable(1);
        sio_set_iobase(SIO_REG_IO_SPI, SIO_SPI_IOBASE);
    sio_pnp_exit();
}

static uint8_t winbond_read_flash_command(uint32_t address)
{
    uint8_t data, lo, mi, hi;
    lo = (address & 0xFF);
    mi = (address >>  8) & 0xFF;
    hi = (address >> 16) & 0x0F;

    /* Read Command. */
    outb(READ_CMD, SIO_SPI_IOBASE);
    /* Address B0 - B7. */
    outb(lo, SIO_SPI_IOBASE + 3);
    /* Address B8 - B15. */
    outb(mi, SIO_SPI_IOBASE + 2);
    /* Execute. */
    hi |= 0x80;
    outb(hi, SIO_SPI_IOBASE + 1);

    /* Wait command execute finished. */
    while (1) {
        data = inb(SIO_SPI_IOBASE + 1);
        data &= 0xF0;
        if (data == 0)
            break;
    }

    /* Read data. */
    data = inb(SIO_SPI_IOBASE + 4);
    return (data);
}

int main(void)
{
    if (ioperm(0, 1024, 1) == -1)
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, NULL);

    configure_spi();
    printf("First ROM byte: %x\n", winbond_read_flash_command(0));

    return (0);
}
```

However, the code always gets stuck in the loop and if I remove it, it always returns 'ff'.

So my question: are there any additional steps that were not mentioned in these documents? I can actually talk to the Super-I/O, identify the Chip ID and etc... but I can't talk at all with this SPI interface.

Comment: There is `at25` driver in the Linux kernel, what you need is a bridge between that one and your IO chip. Maybe it even exists, dunno.